# timer configuration not working in console application c#

Tags: c#, timer, console-application, system.timers.timer

I want to execute a function in every 20 seconds in my console application.

my function is below

```
public abstract class DownloadComponent
{
    private Timer timer;

    public DownloadComponent()
    {
        // Create and configure the timer
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20).TotalMilliseconds; // Set the interval to 2 minutes
        timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
        timer.AutoReset = true; // Make the timer repeat

        // Start the timer
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // This method will be called every 2 minutes
        BulkZipDownload();
    }

    public abstract void BulkZipDownload();
}

public class BulkZipDownloadClass : DownloadComponent
{
    public BulkZipDownloadClass()
    {
        // Additional initialization if needed
    }

    public override void BulkZipDownload()
    {
        try
        {
            // Your bulk zip download logic here
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle exceptions appropriately
        }
    }
}
```

now the problem is `TimerElapsed` function is not getting executed, my application is executing till  `timer.Start();` code but `TimerElapsed` is not getting executed.

I had used Timer in multiple application but faced this issue for the first time and I am sure I am missing something very small.

Thank you for helping!!!

UPDATE: this is how I am executing the code.

```
private void DownloadComponentMethod()
{
    new BulkZipDownloadClass();
}
public static void Main()
{
    Program p = new Program();
    p.DownloadComponentMethod();
}
```

UPDATE 2: Meanwhile I had done something like below

```
public DownloadComponent()
{
    // Create and configure the timer
    //timer = new Timer();
    //timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20).TotalMilliseconds; // Set the interval to 2 minutes
    //timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
    //timer.AutoReset = true; // Make the timer repeat

    //// Start the timer
    //timer.Start();
    int i = 1;
    while (i == 1)
    {
        BulkZipDownload();
        var seconds = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2).TotalMilliseconds;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Convert.ToInt32(seconds));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the program simply *exiting*?  I don't see anything that would keep the application running.  When I test this and simply introduce a `Console.ReadLine();` at the end of `Main()` it seems to work just fine.

Comment: but TimerElapsed function is not getting executed

Comment: How long does it take to do the download?  Code is waiting 20 seconds and then starting the download.  Don't you want to start the download and then wait?  Put break point in code and see if you get to the break point.

Comment: I want to execute this function in the interval of 20 seconds

Comment: @jdweng I am not able to go to that break point

Comment: @Ibrahimshaikh: *"but TimerElapsed function is not getting executed"* - And when you debug, what **is** happening?  Does the program **very quickly** open and then close?  Have you tried adding anything that would keep the program open, such as waiting for console input?  What's the actual goal here?  Are you looking to create a program that runs indefinitely in the background?  Something like a Windows Service perhaps?

Comment: @David after timer.Start(); line I am expecting the program to execute TimerElapsed method. but the method is not getting executed

Comment: Updated my code, this might help you understanding what I wants to achieve

Comment: @Ibrahimshaikh: It gets executed *after 20 seconds*.  If the program doesn't *run* for 20 seconds then it won't get executed.  For example, if the program only runs for 1 second then the 20 second timer won't execute.  Because 1 is less than 20.

Comment: Did you read David's comment?  You are waiting 20 seconds before doing the download, mean time the application exited.  Do like David said and add the ReadLine().

Comment: @jdweng Yes I just read David's comment. thanks a lot David

Answer (score 1):

Look at what your program does:

```
private void DownloadComponentMethod()
{
    new BulkZipDownloadClass();
}
public static void Main()
{
    Program p = new Program();
    p.DownloadComponentMethod();
}
```

It:

1. Creates an instance of `Program`,
2. Invokes a method on that instance,
3. Within that method, creates an instance of `BulkZipDownloadClass`,
4. Immediately exits that method, effectively destroying that instance of `BulkZipDownloadClass` (the internals of garbage collection could be examined here, but it's not necessary because...),
5. Immediately exits the program.

This would all happen within the space of a few milliseconds.  A 20-second timer won't be invoked in the space of a few milliseconds.

Keep the instance of `BulkZipDownloadClass` in scope, and keep the application running for at least 20 seconds.  For example:

```
static void Main()
{
    var downloader = new BulkZipDownloadClass();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

After 20 seconds (indeed, every 20 seconds) the timer will execute, as long as no console input is provided.  Another approach might be to sleep the main thread for some longer amount of time.  For example:

```
static void Main()
{
    var downloader = new BulkZipDownloadClass();
    Thread.Sleep(999999);
}
```

These are just for testing and demonstration of course.  It's not *entirely* clear what this application is really trying to do.  But what *is* clear is that the application needs to be *running* in order to do it.  An application that has stopped running won't continue to run.

If the goal is to have an indefinite ongoing background task, you might want to take a look at something like a Windows Service instead.  Or perhaps an application that minimizes to the Windows System Tray.  Or not even control timing within the application itself but have a simple application that just does this one task, and schedule it using some external task scheduler on the host system.